# Having trouble importing pyodbc into program

Tags: python, pyodbc

When trying to run my program, it fails with error,

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/some/directory/to/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 
2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/me/some/directory/to/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

I've tried finding some solutions on SO, couldn't find much. Im using Mac OS (Sierra v10.12.6). `pip freeze` generates,

```
(testing_environment) AAAAAA0035:directory me$ pip freeze
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pyodbc==4.0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.2.10
Werkzeug==0.14.1
xlrd==1.1.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Not sure what's going on.. coworkers running Windows aren't running into this issue

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. For me, I looked into the file paths the error gave me (both of them) and the "unixodbc" file missing from "/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib"

To fix this, I updated my brew in terminal and then "brew install unixodbc" after that it the import worked for me.

(I'm on Mac OS)